# SQL Server 2008 R2 watch folder for mdf files

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to let a SQL Server watch a folder for `.mdf` files and attach new `.mdf` files automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but is possible to write an app that does just that, see [Obtaining Directory Change Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that you need the MDF **and** the LDF, always. Also there are serious security considerations from attaching untrusted databases, and issues with in-place update of the database files (a drop of a SQL Server 2008 database would be automatically and *irreversibly* upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2 for example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm well aware of the security risks, however I'm dealing with a costumer who wants it this way, and I can't convince him to do it in a better way.